# How to select the best rank according to quantitative values of another variable

Tags: r, ranking, permutation, dataframe

I created a dataframe that looks like this:

```
# Dataframe
GeneID              TrID                PSI  Length Ranking  
ENSMUSG00000089809  ENSMUST00000146396  0.20 431801  3     
ENSMUSG00000089809  ENSMUST00000161516  0.23 354036  2  
ENSMUSG00000089809  ENSMUST00000161148  0.57   5601  1  
ENSMUSG00000044681  ENSMUST00000117098  0.05   4400  2  
ENSMUSG00000044681  ENSMUST00000141196  0.10   1118  1  
ENSMUSG00000044681  ENSMUST00000141601  0.75  44973  5
```

Now I would like to select for each `GeneId` the `TrID` that has the higher `PSI` value with the respective `Ranking`. At the end the output will be like this:

```
# Desired Output Dataframe
GeneID             TrID               PSI Length Ranking     
ENSMUSG00000089809 ENSMUST00000161148 0.57  5601 1      
ENSMUSG00000044681 ENSMUST00000141601 0.75 44973 5
```

After that, I will create a distribution of the `ranking` values and check in which `PSI` value the rank corresponds. I will permute the `Length` values and the `TrID` values in order to perform a control of the distribution.

Comment: Hi whuber should i remove the question or pass it in stackoverflow? Sorry but i have not found this specific question/problem here cross validated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use base R and do:

```
byGeneId = split(1:nrow(Dataframe), Dataframe$GeneId)
whichTopPsi = sapply(byGeneId, function(i) i[which.max(Dataframe[i,'PSI'])])
Dataframe[whichTopPsi,]
```

You could also use `ddply`, which is more general.

```
require(plyr)
ddply(Dataframe, "GeneId", function(d) d[which.max(d[,'PSI']),,drop=FALSE])
```